# No parameterless constructor defined for this object. using asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net

I have this constructor that return list of surveys in database

```
public class SurveysController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
    // GET: Survey/Surveys
     public SurveysController(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var surveys = _db.Surveys.ToList();
        return View(surveys);
    }
}
```

but it gives me error that *No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
* Any Help ?!

Answer (score 1):

The exception is straightforward: you need a parameterless constructor for the controller class, because you have a constructor with one parameter like this:

```
public SurveysController(ApplicationDbContext db)
{
    _db = db;
}
```

Therefore you should add parameterless constructor like this:

```
public SurveysController()
{
    // do something
}
```

Related issues:

[MVC ASP.NET No parameterless constructor defined for this object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16317757/mvc-asp-net-no-parameterless-constructor-defined-for-this-object)

[No parameterless constructor defined for this object. in ASP.NET MVC Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14374242/no-parameterless-constructor-defined-for-this-object-in-asp-net-mvc-controller)